# counting string character in javascript return always 1

Tags: javascript, facebook

Hi everybody this code is used to have a list name and id of facebook friends or invited friends if executed on friend list page. I'm trying to count the character of a string in javascript but `.length` method return always 1. I don't understand why cause I'm counting on a string not an array.

this is my code:

```
var name_list;
var id_list;
var count_letter_l;
var count_name = 0;
var count_id = 0;


var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('_2akq _1box'); 

for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){

  var name = inputs[i].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  var full_id = inputs[i].getAttribute("data-reactid");
  var split_id = full_id.split(':');
  var split_two = split_id[1].split('.');
  var split_final = split_two[0];



  var count_letter = split_final.length;
  //console.log(count_letter);

  if(name != 'null'){
    name_list+= ',' + '"' + name + '"';
    id_list += ',' + '"' + split_final + '"';
    count_letter_l += ',' + '"' + count_letter + '"';
    count_name++;
    count_id++;
  }

}

console.log(name_list);
console.log('------!!!!!!!!------');
console.log(id_list);
console.log('names = ' + count_name);
console.log('id = ' + count_id);
console.log('letters for esch field = ' + count_letter_l);
```

I wish to count the character of every id cause in my case when I grab the ids I have some "0" and "1" in the and of the list. I don't know why and I wish to cut them out of the list.

This is an element of `_2akq _1box` class. you can see it if open firefox firbug and look at facebook front-end html code while you are displaying the friends list

```
<span class="_2akq _1box" data-reactid=".5q.2.0.0.0.0:0:1:$1543522353.0.0.$2.$text.0.0">
<span data-reactid=".5q.2.0.0.0.0:0:1:$1543522353.0.0.$2.$text.0.0.0">Laura Casali</span>
</span>
```

the console tell me:

```
letters for esch field = undefined,"1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1".....
```

tnx for help

Comment: can you provide a sample list item (name and all that which you are splitting), i.e, what's contained inside `_2akq _1box`

Comment: sure? I'm testing it with firebug and it works but the console tell me only 1,1,1,1 .....

Comment: split_final have very strange behaviour. It show a string only when I use it to make the array called id_list. Otherwise it show "1" or "0".

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Solved!!! just miss " " in var declaration

Comment: where you missed it ??